# Point of origin at 0,0,0

Tags: modeling, coordinates, origin

I want to design furniture.

I've got measures from the front wall, side walls and the floor.
When I draw a table of 2.20m long, it is centered in the frame and is positioned at X axis -1.10 to 1.10m.

I need a non centered draw, and the x axis must go from 0 to 2.20m.
How can I do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either move your *origin* (1),
or move your vertices in *edit mode* (2).

**Solution 01. Move the origin**
Set *Transform* to only affect *Origins*
*Sidebar > Tool > Transform only Origins*

Then you can move *Origin point* as any other object.
Disable it again to move your object back to 0,0,0.

[image]

**Solution 02. Move vertices**
Switch to *Edit mode*, select and move vertices.
This will keep the origin point in place.

[image]

Note:
You need to do this for each new object.

Comment: Oh thanks. Trying

Comment: Yep, but must do it with every object I use?

Comment: Yep. Understand me. When I make a measure, is not from center of the wall, is form the floor or the side. Thanks

Comment: YEah. Copying the object instead of create new ones could solve it. Thanks

Comment: Yep. It solves it respect the object. But not from the scene. I still need to set location in negative numbers. I need my starting point at x,y,z at 0,0,0.Is it possible?

Comment: Yep. I need to design a furniture. I`ve got the measures from the wall, the side wall and the floor. When i need to draw a table of 2.20m long, it is centered in the frame and is positioned at X axis -1.10 to 1.10m. I need a non centered draw, and the x axis must go from 0 to 2.20m. Is it clear? Sorry for my english, I`m Tarzan's son.

Comment: Yes! You are the one! MAny thanks

Comment: Hello :). If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted **✓**, so others can easily find it. Thanks a lot :).

Comment: Sorry. Can't find the √. …

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to move an object's origin directly to 0,0,0 is to press ALT+G to automatically set the object's origin to the center. It does not matter where the cursor is for this to work, because the cursor has nothing to do with any of it. You can also reset the object's rotation by using the similar ALT+R.